# How do I embed 3 view controllers into 1 view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a `RestaurantViewController`. I'd like to embed 3 view controllers directly to fill this parent.  (not covering nav bar of course).

In the navigation bar, there will be a button.
As I tap this button, the visibility of the 3 VCs will cycle. (no animations, just hiding/showing).

When I tap the button, I want the 3 childrens to respect events `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, etc...  Does changing the `hidden`  property call these?

How can I do this?

My theory is to create 3 containers and add them to `RestaurantViewController.view`, then set hidden for them as I tap the button. I'm not sure if this is the "right" way.

Comment: Why do you think this is not the right way? And I don't think the child view will call `viewWillDisappear` when u just hide it, need to remove it from the view hierarchy and re-add it

Comment: Sure, You can use container view for it. It is bit easy for you

Comment: Look at this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You want to use child view controllers and probably the method `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`

Answer (score 3):

If you want each child to have it's own area of the screen then using 3 different containers with a different child in each will work fine.

No, viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear will not be called each time the child's hidden flag switches from true to false. As Tj3n says, that will only be called if the child view controller's view is removed from the screen and then re-added.

### EDIT:

If you have a single container view that you want to replace with a different child view controller each time you press a button then you want to use the parent/child view controller methods in UIViewController. See the section "Implementing a Container View Controller" in the Xcode docs on UIViewController.

You could add your starting child view controller to the container using an embed segue, and add the others using `addChildViewController`.

There are also methods that let you transition from one child to another, like `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`. That's a very powerful method that lets you swap child view controllers with a wide variety of transition effects. That's the method that you'd trigger when the user pressed the button to swap view controllers.

Comment: I think what he wants to achieve is the same tabbar functionality but using one button to navigate sequentially between the three view controllers.

Comment: Yes, Ahmad is right. How can I achieve TabBar functionality with one button to switch tabs?

Comment: Would `transitionFromViewController:toViewController` cause `viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear` ?

Comment: @TIMEX I just tested it on an app I wrote that uses child view controllers and `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`. Yes, `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` are called as the view controllers transition on and off screen, as I was pretty sure the would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 3 UIViewControllers to the main view controller, but none of them will call viewWillAppear.
Instead of playing with the property hidden you can add a tag value to each view do something like:

```
-(void)changeViews:(int) index {
    if (lastDisplayedView == 1) {
        // code you wanted in viewWillDisappear for view 1
    } else if (lastDisplayedView == 2) {
        // code you wanted in viewWillDisappear for view 2
    } else if (lastDisplayedView == 3) {
        // code you wanted in viewWillDisappear for view 3
    }
    UIView *viewToRemove = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:lastDisplayedView];
    [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    UIView *viewToShow = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:index];
    [self.view addSubview:viewToShow];
    lastDisplayedView = index;

    // code you need to do when view appears
}
```